# C# : insert data into database using linq

Tags: c#, database, string, linq, insert

i want to insert the data into my database, using linq. i follow the [instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx), then i do some coding here, based on the followed instruction

```
 private void addNasabah()
    {
        char gender = cekRadio();

        customer customer = new customer()
        {
            nomor_customer = int.Parse(innomor.Text),
            nama = innama.Text.ToString(),
            jenis_kelamin = gender,
            alamat = inalamat.Text.ToString(),
            nomor_telepon = innomor.Text.ToString(),
            saldo = 0
        };

        dc.customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            cmd.cetakSukses("Berhasil Menyimpan Nasabah", "Tambah Nasabah");
            innomor.Text = genNextId().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal(e.ToString(), "Tambah Nasabah");                                
        }

    }
```

here is `cekRadio()` method

```
 private char cekRadio()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            return 'p';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'w';
        }
    }
```

but i encountered some error, here's the error
[image: error]

the picture said "input string was not in a correct format" .

what is the expected string correct format ?

here is my `genNextId()` method

```
  private int genNextId()
    {
        int id = (from a in dc.customers
                  select a.nomor_customer).Max();

        return id+1;
    }
```

i try running the application, the messagebox showed "Berhasil Menyimpan Nasabah", "Tambah Nasabah" but then i checked in my database, the entered data wasn't there.

here is my `customer` table on the database
[image: missing attribute]

Comment: idk, the error pointing on the yellow-marked line on the picture.

Comment: What is the value of `innomor.Text` ?

Comment: This code throws the exception: `int.Parse(innomor.Text)`. Check the content of `innomor.Text`

Comment: may be the error at int.parse method try another converting to int methods...

Comment: convert.toint32(text.tostring()) use this one

Comment: OMG. my bad, `innomor.Text = "NAS"+genNextId().ToString();`  so i have deleted the "NAS" but the data is not saved on my database

Comment: are you getting any value into this field  `genNextId().ToString();`

Comment: @pratapk yeah i get the last Id to generate newer Id. on my table, there's 1 record with `nomor_customer` value = 1

Comment: You should have this field as an **Identity** field, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: The error is in the creation of the customer object, so take a look at the values you're trying to assign to the properties - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a break point next to this line `Customer customer = new Customer()` and you can now check what the value of each variable is, the `int.Parse()` could be an issue if the string is not able to be **parsed into an integer**.

Also, make sure the properties of `Customer` are the **expected types**, check `jenis_kelamin` for example.

Another (unrelated to bug) point, if you're using **[Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)** i.e **new Object {}**, then you can drop the parenthesis (), so you would have...

```
Customer customer = new Customer { ..properties.. };
```

**EDIT**: In light of some of the comments you have posted, I need to point out the way you are retrieving the **Next ID** is a bad approach.  I specified in one of the comments above that you should use an [**Identity**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) field in SQL, this way you set the `seed` and `increment`, and SQL will generate the next ID on your behalf.

Comment: yes i have fix that line. here is my `innomor` line `innomor.Text = genNextId().ToString();`

Comment: err yes, now the error is the entered data is not saved in my database :( sorry for confusing you guys

Comment: put a break at `dc.customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);` and see if you have a valid customer, you seem to be getting the **new id** after calling `dc.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: the new ID will be shown for the next insertion. what is "break" ? is it like new line ? or `break;` ?

Comment: and then ? it didn't show "Berhasil Menyimpan Nasabah" messagebox

Comment: confirm that the object to be inserted into the table is correct by highlighting **customer** in here `dc.customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);` and right click, Add to watch.  You can then inspect the properties.